# Exit do loop when condition isn't met / Output answer incorrect

Tags: c

2 questions. 1 - I'm struggling to figure out how to exit this loop when a negative number is entered. 2 - my section of code regarding checking if the sum of the digits of a number isn't working correctly and need a different equation to get the correct output but cant figure it out. That part of the code needs to add the digits of an integer and output whether the sum is odd or even.

```
int main(void)

{
  int number, sum, i;
  int divisor, prime;

  do {
    printf("Enter an integer:");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    i = number;
    sum = 0;

    if (i % 7 == 0) {
      printf("Multiple of 7\n");
    } else if (i % 11 == 0) {
      printf("Multiple of 11\n");
    } else if (i % 13 == 0) {
      printf("Multiple of 13\n");
    }

    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      printf("Is sum of digits Odd? 1\n");
    } else {
      printf("Is sum of digits Odd? 0\n");
    }

    int check = 1;
    for (divisor = 2; divisor <= i / 2; ++divisor) {
      if (i % divisor == 0) {
        check = 0;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (check == 0) printf("Is number prime? 0\n");
    else printf("Is number prime? 1\n");

  } while (i > 0);

  return (0);
}
```

Comment: Pro Tip: Nobody wants to read code that doesn't have indentation...

Comment: 1) What is your sample input?  2) What it the output?  3) What is the expected output and why?

Comment: sorry, @Allen, code is in online homework format and is not indented properly.

Comment: Do you write this code?

Comment: You will make your life easier by formatting your code. My roommate asked for help on college work and I just fixed the indentation, then they figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
...    
do {
    printf("Enter an integer:");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    if ( number < 0 ) 
        break ;
...
```

Comment: @Michi. Nothing of course but I think OP is looping for a way to stop his loop as soon as a negative number is entered **without** checking if number is multiple of seven etc...

Comment: My bad, sorry was a fast read, you use number<0. Here is almost 4 a clock in the morning :)

Comment: @Michi then we are in the same timezone :-)

Answer (score 0):

One way to exit a loop with certain condition in C is using `BREAK`

```
if( a < 0) {
         /* terminate the loop using break statement */
         break;
}
```

Comment: The way to exit...or one way to exit? Anyway the OP does the same without the need of break

Comment: @chux with only    `while( i > 0)` the code still runs when a negative number is entered

Comment: Well it will exit after completing the remainder of the loop body but this is probably not what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

When a negative number is entered, you can check with an if condition just after taking the input, and use `exit(0)`. 
Like

```
if(number < 0)
    exit(0);
```

What you *are* doing will not work. Because you've used the `while` condition at the end, the modulus functions may not work(I'm not so sure, but I think the modulus function needs a positive integer as an argument)

You're not checking the sum of digits of the number in your code, but only if the number itself is even or odd.
The part would be

```
while(i > 0)
{
    sum += i % 10;
    i /= 10;
}
```

That should give you the sum of the digits, and you can check if it is odd or even

Anyway, the prime part will completely fail when a negative number, or even 1 is entered.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you don't want to enter the loop at all, you can use a while loop instead of a do while loop.

You would have to get the first input before entering the loop, though, and would need another input at the bottom of the loop. This probably isn't what you want.

You probably want to use

`if (number < 0) break;`

And that would go right after you read the value.

If you do this, you don't need

`while (i > 0);`

At the end of your loop, you can just use

`while (true);`

Personally, I use while loops in such cases but that's really just a stylistic choice.

In any case, there is no need to check the value twice.

Comment: this is giving me a logic error for some reason. entered it correctly as well. im starting to think the compiler this website uses isnt working correctly.